# When to use a printf statement in Java?

Tags: java, formatting, printf

When is it considered good code to format a string output like this:

```
int count = 5;
double amount = 45.6;
System.out.printf("The count is %d and the amount is %45.6", count, amount);
```

utilising a printf statement, over code like this:

```
int count = 5;
double amount = 45.6;
System.out.print("The count is " + count + "and the amount is " + amount);
```

using a print statement?

I have read the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) which state that printf is "A convenience method to write a formatted string to this output stream using the specified format string and arguments."

But it doesn't state when, by convention, we should use one over the other?

So, when is it good coding to use a printf, and when is it good coding not to?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm really interested more-so in the conventions, when is it good code/ easier to read or debug to use one over the other. This isn't really answered in the other question, but thanks for finding it anyway there are some really good answers on it.

Comment: this is been answered in - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548249/is-there-a-good-reason-to-use-printf-instead-of-print-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two methods are provided for the convenience of a coder and for different needs. If you need string formatting then go for printf method but if there is no formatting required simply use print method and void %d,%s, etc formatters.

If you want to control the precision & padding of floating point numbers then use printf otherwise go for print.

Comment: But how would the formatting differ from one form to another? Could you maybe give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

printf was added quite recently in the history of java as a convenience because so many people were used to C style printf and what it could do. so one isnt really better or preferred over the other. Regular "print" style though is clearer and simpler when special printf formatting isnt required.