# Java print variations

Tags: java

I'm new to Java, and have a bit of confusion between three output options: print, println and printf.

I understand that println gives the result while automatically putting each new line under each other, but I can't seem to find a difference between print and printf?

Example:

```
int numOne=10;
int numTwo=15;
int numThree=20;

System.out.printf("Number one is %d\n Number two is %d\n Number three is %d",numOne,numTwo,numThree);
```

Yet the above example won't work with print... So what makes these two different, and when would I know which one of the three to use when?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a good reason to use "printf" instead of "print" in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548249/is-there-a-good-reason-to-use-printf-instead-of-print-in-java)

Comment: `print` prints out the text, `println` prints out the text and adds a line feed and `printf` uses String formatting

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that in the search results.... @Ascalonian thanks, that cleared it up quite nicely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Println() will display its parameters in the command window, and in the end with a newline, beginning to output the cursor in the next row.

Print() will  display its parameters in the command window, and the output cursor position after the last character display.

Printf() will  display formatted output form, it's a method of the PrintStream class that provides string formatting(), and it can be useful when displaying multiple variables in one line.