# What is the benefit of using System.out.print over System.out.printf?

Tags: java, printf, system.out, printstream

I have a question similar to [Is there a good reason to use "printf" instead of "print" in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548249/is-there-a-good-reason-to-use-printf-instead-of-print-in-java).  That question asks and is answered about the benefits of using `System.out.print` over `System.out.printf`.  I am curious about the benefits to using `System.out.print` over `System.out.printf` in the first place.

In my experience, I see `System.out.print` used drastically more often than `System.out.printf`.

With `System.out.printf`, it is more readable when formatting numbers.  You still have the syntactic sugar of concatenating strings with `+`'s, as seen in the second System.out.  `System.out.printf` also returns a `PrintStream` in case you want to do anything with it.

Examples:

```
int hour = 6;
int minutes = 5;
int seconds = 4;
System.out.printf("Time: %d:%02d:%02d", hour, minutes, seconds);
System.out.printf("Time: " + hour + ":%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
System.out.print("Time: " + hour + ":" + String.format("%02d", minutes) + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds));
//Output for each line:  Time: 6:05:04

System.out.printf("Print something!");
System.out.print("Print something!");
//Output for each line:  "Print something!"

System.out.printf("End a line\n");
System.out.println("End a line");
//Output for each line:  End a line [followed by a line break]

String x = "a variable";
System.out.printf("Add %s", x);
System.out.printf("Add " + x);
System.out.print("Add " + x);
//Output for each line:  Add a variable
```

So aside from (I think) majority of Java programmers using `System.out.print`, what is the benefit to it over `System.out.printf`?  Is there a noticeable difference in memory or time efficiency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` with string concatenation will be marginally more efficient than `printf`.  With `print`, you the developer are determining at compilation time where the values need to be inserted into the string, but with `printf`, you're asking the JRE to parse your format string and insert the values at runtime.  Unless you're doing a large amount of printing, this is likely to be a negligible difference, so you should go with whatever is easiest to maintain.