# Errors displaying numbers in pyramid array function in Java

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

The following class `DoubleArray` is used to create and display pyramid arrays.
When trying to test the code there was a problem in displaying numbers in the pyramid array as the picture below shows. Where can be the error in the following code ?

```
public class DoubleArray {
  public static double[] createSequenceArray(int size){
    double[] array;
    array = createZerosArray(size);
    for(int i=0 ; i< size ; i++){
        array[i]=i;
    }
    return array;
}
  public static String arrayToString(double[] dblArray){
      String container="";
      for (double item : dblArray){
        container =container + item +" ";
      }
      return container;
  }   
  public static String arrayToString(double[][] dblMatrix){
      String container ="";
      for (double[] item: dblMatrix){
        container = container + arrayToString(item)+"\n";
      }
      return container;
  }
  public static double[][] createPyramidArray(int maxRows){
        double [][] array = new double[maxRows][]; 
        for(int i=0; i<maxRows;i++){    
        array[i] = new double[i+1];
        for(int j = 0; j<array[i].length;j++){
            array[i][j]=(j+1)*1.1;
        }
        }
        return array;
   }
 }
}
```

Code for main function

```
public class ArrayTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    double[] arrayUn; 
    double[][] arrayDb;
    arrayUn = DoubleArray.createSequenceArray(12);
    System.out.println(DoubleArray.arrayToString(arrayUn));
    arrayDb = DoubleArray.createPyramidArray(7);
    System.out.println(DoubleArray.arrayToString(arrayDb));
 }
}
```

The console shows the following: 3.3000000000000003 is printed instead of 3.3

[image]

Comment: where is `createSequenceArray`?

Comment: Screen shot is the o/p of what `createSequenceArray` or `createPyramidArray` ??

Comment: Both of them. The first line is for srquence array the rest is for pyramid array

Comment: I am saying why numbers are displayed in that way I want to display them as 1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4  but as I see some numbers were displayed as 3.30000003 and 6.0000005 istead of 3.3 and 6.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is not in you printing logic but it is the behavior of Java floating point numbers. When you do `3 * 1.1` you get `3.3000000000000003`. That's the way IEE 754 floating point arithmetic works.

Check this:

```
    double d1 = 1 * 1.1;
    double d2 = 3 * 1.1;
    System.out.println(d1); //Output 1.1
    System.out.println(d2); //Output 3.3000000000000003
```

To fix this you can use Java's `printf()` method which lets you print the formatted string. So you can use something like `System.out.printf("%.1f", d2);`

Read more about [Java's formatted numeric printing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).

---

Edit based on OP's comment:

Root cause is highlighted in my answer, and partial solution as well. Basically what you need is formatted double value. For that you can use `java.text.DecimalFormat` to format the double value as per your needs. Below what you can do to solve your problem:

```
    double d2 = 3 * 1.1;
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(".#");
    String d2n = decimalFormat.format(d2);
    System.out.println(d2); //Outputs - 3.3000000000000003
    System.out.println(d2n);  //Outputs - 3.3
```

Comment: I am not seeking to simply print out. I seek to concatenate every case of the array in that array then print the final result. Sorry your answer does not answer my question.

Comment: @pentanol Buddy, once root cause is known putting a fix should not be a problem. Moreover you also asked to identity the root cause. Anyways check my edited answer. You need to use `DecimalFormat` in your `arrayToString` class. Please feel free to let me know in case of any question.

Answer (score 0):

To fix it print your string like

```
System.out.printf("%.1f", DoubleArray.arrayToString(arrayDb));
```

Here you can find why and what https://stackoverflow.com/a/548287/5594180

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think array[i].length will ever work. Another thing which is troubling you is multiplication, try adding 1.1 instead.
ADD 1.1 to your previous result while looping through the row

Comment: I am not seeking to simply print out. I seek to concatenate every case of the array in that array then print the final result. Sorry your answer does not answer my question.