# Java: print double - println or printf

Tags: java, printf, println

Suppose I have the following code:

```
double median = med(10.0, 12.0, 3.0); //method returns middle number as double
```

Now, I want to write a message stating the median. Can this be done using **println()**, like the following:

```
System.out.println("Your number was " + median);
```

Or must I use **printf()** with double values?

The reason I ask is because I have seen both practices online [1](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-display-double-in-2-decimal-points/), but when I try using **println()** I get an error, unless i write:

```
System.out.println(median);
```

Hence, can you use **println()** to print out **double** values and **strings**, or must you use **printf()** for that purpose?

Comment: I don't receive an error when writing "System.out.println("Your number was " + median);" Does this really throw an error for you? if yes which one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a good reason to use "printf" instead of "print" in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548249/is-there-a-good-reason-to-use-printf-instead-of-print-in-java)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `printf` method can be particularly useful when displaying multiple variables in one line which would be tedious using string concatenation:
The `println()` which can be confusing at times. (Although both can be used in almost all cases).

```
 double a = 10;
 double b = 20;

System.out.println("a: " + a + " b: " + b);// Tedious string concatenation.

System.out.printf("a: %f b: %f\n", a, b);// Output using string formatting.
```

Output:

```
a: 10.0 b: 20.0
a: 10,000000 b: 20,000000
```

Answer (score 2):

[You can do both](https://ideone.com/D1Fdev) (if `System.out.println("Your number was " + median);` is not working you have something else wrong. Show us the stack trace). `printf` allows you some more [formatting options](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) (such as the number of decimal places) without having to use a [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), but it is a choice on style rather than anything else.

Personally I find string concatenation easer on the eyes and easer to maintain. The `%blah` gets lost in the string, errors in string concatenation is a compile time error and adding a new variable requires less thought. However I'm in the minority on this.

The pros in `printf` is that you don't need to construct a bunch of formatters, others find its format easer on the eyes and when using a printf like method provided by a logging framework the string building only happens if actually required.

```
double value = 0.5;
System.out.println("value: " + value);
System.out.printf("value: %f", value);
```

If you want to [set a number of decimal places](https://ideone.com/N5rmB0):

```
    double value = 0.5;
    // String concatenation 
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
    System.out.println("value: " + df.format(value));

    // printf
    System.out.printf("value: %.3f", value);
```