# Java help translating printf syntax to print

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand printf syntax. Specifically, I need to know what...

```
System.out.printf("%3s%12s%12s\n", "Sum", "Frequency", "Percentage");
```

...would translate to when using a print rather than printf statement.

Comment: When you read the `printf` javadoc, what confused you about the conversion characters?

Comment: If you're referring to the Oracle Javadoc entry for "Formatting numeric print output", I'm just not getting it. If I could 'see' a translation, maybe it would help it sink in. The JAVA class I'm in is the only exposure I've had to the language, and we're only using zyBooks with no other references. Maybe I should have put "Java novice" in all caps. -Thanks for any help!

Comment: Actually, this is all very helpful (especially your response). Thank you.
One last thing? What is the advantage with using printf? From my (admittedly ignorant) perspective, it just seems unnecessarily cryptic.
@Awanish I think it's getting downvoted because I don't know enough to ask a better question.

Comment: @MicahWolfe.. please see below post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548249/is-there-a-good-reason-to-use-printf-instead-of-print-in-java

Answer (score 0):

That would be:

```
System.out.print("Sum   Frequency  Percentage\n");
//                --^-----------^-----------^
//                  3           12          12 positions, all right-aligned
```

Answer (score 0):

printf is a convenience method to write a formatted string to this output stream using the specified format string and arguments.

Parameters:

format - A format string as described in Format string syntax

args - Arguments referenced by the format specifiers in the format string.

In your statement,

```
 System.out.printf("%3s%12s%12s\n", "Sum", "Frequency", "Percentage");
```

format - %s - indicates your format is a string

If you use "%s%s%s" - It indicates you are going to print 3 string arguments.

%3s%12s%12s  indicates that you want to leave spaces before printing arguments

Hence your output would be

Sum      Frequency       Percentage

Trying printing these:

```
 System.out.printf("%3s%100s%12s\n", "Sum", "Frequency", "Percentage");
```

You would notice lot of space between first and second arguments

Try doing this:

```
 System.out.printf("%3s%10s\n", "Sum", "Frequency", "Percentage");
```

You notice that third string "Percentage" is not printed as you have mentioned only two "%s" in the format.

Answer (score -1):

**In your question**

`System.out.print("Sum Frequency Percentage ")` will do the work

**Extra**

While using printf statement you  have to use format specifiers like:
 `System.out.printf("%3s%12s%12s\n", "Sum", "Frequency", "Percentage");`

here
`%3s%12s%12s` are format specifiers **to help string formatting**

In print statement `System.out.print( "Sum", "Frequency", "Percentage");`
you don't have to use any format specifiers here.

**Ex:**

`system.out.print("The output is :"+output)`

`system.out.printf("The output is %d",output)`

In printf statement, the `%d` will be the placeholder of integer `output`