# What is the difference between println and printf?

Tags: java

What is the difference between `println` and `printf`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548249/is-there-a-good-reason-to-use-printf-instead-of-print-in-java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a good reason to use "printf" instead of "print" in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548249/is-there-a-good-reason-to-use-printf-instead-of-print-in-java)

Comment: Check the Javadoc for [println](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println--) and [printf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`println` adds a new line at the end of the output, so you cant continue on that line and `printf` supports format strings so you can pass arguments that are substituted into the string e.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.printf("%s %s", "hello", "world");
    System.out.printf(" - with something else on the same line");
}
```

will print

```
hello world - with something else on the same line
```

Answer (score 3):

If you looking for simple answer. There are 3 standard ways to print something in console:

1. System.out.print() - prints without adding new line in the end

```
System.out.print("aaa");
System.out.print("bbb");
```

result in the console:

```
aaabbb
```

2. System.out.println() - prints with new line in the end

```
System.out.println("aaa");
System.out.println("bbb");
```

result in the console:

```
aaa
bbb
```

3. System.out.printf() - prints with formatting. This is more complex, but more agile command. 
   %s used as simple placeholder for string (described in accepted answer) 
   %S can be used to make text in upper case 
   %f for float or double formatting 
   %d for integers 
   Also possible to format dates and so on.

Most common case here - printing number with rounding (precision).

```
double number = 1.2345678f;
System.out.printf("%.2f", number); // .2 means 2 digits after comma
```

prints 1.23 instead of 1.2345678

You can also use \n in the any String to make new line.